# Force cspade to only look at rules involving specific items using R package arulesSequences

Tags: r

Is it possible to force cspade to only look at rules that involve certain items? 
For example the following code provides output showing all the rules created based on the parameters in the cspade function:

```
library(Matrix)
library(arules)
library(arulesSequences)
x <- read_baskets(con = system.file("misc", "zaki.txt", package = 
"arulesSequences"), 
              info = c("sequenceID","eventID","SIZE"))
s1 <- cspade(x, parameter = list(support = 0.4), control = list(verbose = TRUE))
as(s1, "data.frame")

          sequence support
1            <{A}>    1.00
2            <{B}>    1.00
3            <{D}>    0.50
4            <{F}>    1.00
5          <{A,F}>    0.75
6          <{B,F}>    1.00
7        <{D},{F}>    0.50
8      <{D},{B,F}>    0.50
9        <{A,B,F}>    0.75
10         <{A,B}>    0.75
11       <{D},{B}>    0.50
12       <{B},{A}>    0.50
13       <{D},{A}>    0.50
14       <{F},{A}>    0.50
15   <{D},{F},{A}>    0.50
16     <{B,F},{A}>    0.50
17 <{D},{B,F},{A}>    0.50
18   <{D},{B},{A}>    0.50
```

I want to tell cspade to just look for rules that involve {D}. I know that I could just filter out the rules containing {D} after all the rules are created with something like:

```
as(s1, "data.frame") %>%
filter(grepl("D", sequence, fixed = TRUE))
```

I also know that I could pre-filter before running the cspade to only include items that have {D} (all my SequenceIDs contain D somewhere).

For the data that I have, it is much larger with a lot more items, sequences, and events. All the sequenceIDs contain {D} somewhere, but {D} is a rare event and I only want to see what leads up to {D}. I am not interested in rules like <{B,F},{A}>.

I know that I can set the support to be really low to try and catch all the times that {D} shows up, but my computer won't run it because there is too much data.

I have looked at a number of arulesSequences examples on stackoverflow and other sites and haven't found how to do this yet.

Comment: Why can't you just use the `subset` function in the arules package?

Comment: I may be wrong, but from what I can tell from the examples that I have seen, the subset function is performed after the rules are made. I am trying to subset while the rules are made so that certain rules aren't evaluated.